# MVC4 using Npgsql and Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2012 or higher

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, npgsql

I have VS2012 and I want to connect to postgresql with Entity Framwork (ADO.NET) but the [best solution](http://fxjr.blogspot.fr/2011/05/npgsql-design-time-support-preview.html) I found seems to be for VS2010.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClLa1zP80Lc) using VS2012 but when I build the project I get the error `The name 'VSConstants' does not exist in the current context` among others. I cannot figure out what the error means.

I even tried installing dotconnect for postgre but after installing the required libraries and adding DBfactory connection string, I still do not see .NET data provider for PostgreSQL in my data connection dialogue. I wonder what I am not doing right. I am stuck here. I hope my question is clear enough. Help please

Answer (score 0):

> I even tried installing dotconnect for postgre but after installing
>   the required libraries and adding DBfactory connection string, I still
>   do not see .NET data provider for PostgreSQL in my data connection
>   dialogue.

1. Have you installed the Professional edition of dotConnect for PostgreSQL? You can check your current edition via the Tools > PostgreSQL > About menu of Visual Studio. Only Professional edition includes the Entity Framework support: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/editions.html.
2. Using Devart PgSqlExtendedMembership Provider in ASP.NET MVC 4 Application: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?ExtendedMembership-Tutorial.html.
3. If you have any questions about dotConnect for PostgreSQL, please contact us via http://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html.